# What is the best way of inserting data into SQL Server in parallel?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to insert data from MS Access (`.mdb`) file into SQL Server 2014 Standard edition. Each file contains 100 tables. I have more than three thousand files to be loaded into SQL Server. Out of the 100 tables, some are loaded to a common table and the rest of them to individual tables in SQL Server.

Currently it is doing using Microsoft Jet.4.0 through a front end loop over file list and then over table list. The process takes three to four days to be completed that is not efficient enough.

I want to make the maximum use of server resources and minimize the operation time. My server has 128GB RAM with 32 core processors in Active-Passive cluster environment. How can I insert all files in parallel or in any efficient approach?

**What I have tried:**

I have coded a multi threaded program to send insert requests to the SQL Server which I found sending multiple requests to the SQL Server at the same time but the SQL Server is processing those requests serially. As a consequence, there is no improvement of performance.

I tried SQL Server Agent Job, which demonstrates to be parallel, however it seems to be difficult to control to me.

If we calculate, one file takes 2 min lo be loaded and there are three thousand of them. So, six thousand minutes that is 4.16 day. Average file size is around 100 mb. I found no working method even after googling and testing every method I have found each day of last couple of the months.

Is there any suitable way to insert data efficiently?

Comment: Have you tried DTS? It is very efficient. Ir looks difficult but using standard import from Enterprise Mánager and then  store the steps it create the DTS for you. Then you need to customize for multiple files

Comment: If this is a one time job, why dont you Just let it use 4 days to complete. If you cant find anything very Quick, you might Just end up using more time than these 4 days.

Comment: Dear Zach, thank you for your interest in this issue. To illustrate, this is a monthly basis regular process. We receive all data files by first or second day of every month and need to complete consolidation and prepare reports for higher management by 5th, which leads us to take the issue into account.

Comment: Then you should separate the import by where it will be saved. You should try to have a thread for each table you are inserting into. I dont know how you are inserting the data, but using sql commands with parametere might be faster than using for example linq. You can also execute multiple inserts at once. There might also be triggers or constraints slowing down the insert. Also look into how foreign Keys are and if you are using transactions which might block other insert queries.

Comment: @AngelM. DTS was replaced by SSIS a long time ago...

Comment: I've used the SQL Server Bulk Insert from CSV files for tasks like this. I'll post an example when I'm in the office tomorrow. You'd need to export the tables to CSV first. The Bulk Insert is pretty quick.

Comment: Your multithreaded job should do the trick.  My suspicion is that the job is establishing the connection to SQL Server and then forking.  You should have a separate connection in each thread.

Comment: Also I did a similar work on Oracle SQL and there was a way of import data in an appropriate format on system level (via console script) if this is applicable in your case it can speedup the process as well.


I would also try to have MDB data in a better input format (CSV per table?), e.g. the provider of these data files do more work before providing it to you to speedup the process. Or sync data more often and then at the end of month do just the last few days ...

Comment: Your server has memory and processor, but what about storage? Are you using SSDs with high-bandwidth connections? RAID 0? Database and transaction log on separate volumes? Have a look with Resource Monitor and see if I/O is a bottleneck.

Comment: @HABO We are using SSD storage with SAN switch and it is RAID 5. Transaction log is separated to another volume. Database has five file groups. We found no I/O bottleneck for a program which is being used to unzip all the mdb files which we receive as a zip file. It is incredibly fast. Then, where the bottleneck may lie?

Comment: Loading 100 mb should never take 2 minutes - maybe 10 seconds! There must be something wrong with your server's settings or programming. First load on file in acceptable time. Then try to work parallel.

Comment: Two ways to approach: 1. Work out if individual file load process can be sped up - are you doing a slow row by row operation; 2. It sounds like you are still loading files one by one. You'll need to work out how you can truly get these loading in parallel. This might mean running a bunch of seperate processes, not one multi threaded process.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add an unhelpful comment - and I'm not trying to be snarky - just a little historical perspective from an older developer.  This is a classic 1980s nightmare design...and why the invention of the web was such a boom.  Clearly the real solution to this is to move to a web application using a common SQL back end server rather than attempting to collect these 1000s of data sets as a batch...….   Having said that - I do understand that there are areas where the infrastructure isn't there for the web.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using DtsWizard.exe - it will generate a package on the fly that you can save off and modify.  You can use it to become familiar with SSIS and all the options of loading - ie. parallel loading, fast loading, etc.

More importantly - I also recommend disabling triggers and indexes *before* loading.  This can make a huge difference.  If you have FK indexes you can explore leaving them on - it can help in some cases.

Another option is bulk loading - you can use the command line - or c# SqlBulkCopy class - and set the options accordingly to bypass triggers, etc.  Folks have mentioned loading records should be faster than what you are experiencing, some of these little options can kill performance.

Also, are you loading blobs?  xml?  Do you have xml indexes?

Answer (score 0):

because a bulk insert job can hold lock on the database file, consider **augmenting the number of files** of the system **tempdb** database AND your destination database.

It is recommended to use as many files as the number of CPUs(available for SQL Server)-(it is not the default installation option on SQL2014), adding a few more won't harm and can sometimes lower the latches, even more if you have **several disk partitions**, on different channels.
then you can choose to store a table on one partition file.
I also would recommend using Sql Server Agent with multiple jobs, each one with a simple bulk insert cmd line